# GraphViz: fixing only the y position of nodes

Tags: graphviz

I want to pin the y position of nodes, but have the x positions aligned automatically according to force direction.

Each y position is individual because it corresponds to a coordinate on the y axis, and there are several thousand nodes, so I don't think using a sub graph for each node is reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Wrote my own Java2D / PDFGraphics2D function with a simple force directed layout. GraphViz is quite annoying when you have already a quite clear idea about how the layout should look.

[image]