# GraphViz ignores my node positions

Tags: graphviz

I can't get GraphViz to respect some node positions, even though they have `pos` attributes with `!`. E.g.:

```
digraph Versions {
  ranksep=0.05;
  node [style=filled, shape=point, fillcolor=black, fixedsize=true, width=0.3, height=0.1, fontname="Helvetica", fontsize=8, fontcolor=white];
  edge [arrowhead=none, len=0.1];
  2 [pos="0,0!", fillcolor=red];
  3 [pos="20,0!", fillcolor=red];
  4 [pos="40,0!", fillcolor=red];
  5 [pos="60,0!", fillcolor=red];
  6 [pos="80,0!", fillcolor=red];
  7 [pos="100,0!", fillcolor=red];
  8 [pos="120,0!", fillcolor=red];
  9 [pos="140,0!", fillcolor=red];
  10 [pos="160,0!", fillcolor=red];
  11 [pos="180,0!", fillcolor=red];
  12 [pos="200,0!", fillcolor=red];
  13 [pos="220,0!", fillcolor=red];
  2 -> 14;
  14 -> 15;
  3 -> 16;
  16 -> 17;
  11 -> 18;
  18 -> 19;
  6 -> 20;
  20 -> 21;
  10 -> 22;
  22 -> 23;
  13 -> 24;
  24 -> 25;
  9 -> 26;
  26 -> 27;
  4 -> 28;
  28 -> 29;
  7 -> 30;
  30 -> 31;
  5 -> 32;
  32 -> 33;
  8 -> 34;
  34 -> 35;
  12 -> 36;
  36 -> 37;
  15 -> 38;
  38 -> 39;
  17 -> 40;
  40 -> 41;
  19 -> 42;
  42 -> 43;
  // etc.
}
```

The top most rank should be evenly distributed, but *is not*. The horizontal spacing between the top most nodes is not the same:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of the [`pos`](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#dpos) attribute:

> In neato and fdp, pos can be used to set the initial position of a node.

**Are you using *neato* or *fdp*?** Because *dot* does not respect this attribute.

---

Assuming you're using neato, here's an excerpt from the [manual](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/neato.1.pdf):

> **-n[1|2]** (no-op) If set, neato assumes nodes have already been positioned and all nodes have a pos attribute giving the positions

This means you can render a graph with

```
neato -n2 -Tpng mygraph.gv -o mygraph.png
```

and have neato respect the pos attributes (in points) of the nodes.

This also states that **all** nodes must have a pos attribute.

Since some nodes of your graph do not have a pos attribute, this will lead to an error.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't using neato. Not being able to constrain x/y independently didn't work though in my case. [I wrote my own layout thus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424665/graphviz-fixing-only-the-y-position-of-nodes/19451579#19451579)